# R: Subsetting data frame for minimum of consecutive years

Tags: r, aggregate, data-cleaning

I have a large data frame with the following structure:

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10), rep("C", 10), rep("D", 10)), 
                   year = rep(2008:2017, 4), 
                   value = c(rnorm(10, mean = 100, sd = 20), 
                             rnorm(10, mean = 100, sd = 20), 
                             rnorm(4, mean = 100, sd = 20), 
                             rep(NA, 2), 
                             rnorm(4, mean = 100, sd = 20), 
                             rnorm(2, mean = 100, sd = 20), 
                             rep(NA, 8))
                  )
```

First, I wish to clean the data by only including data for those `id`s that have `value` data for at least five years out of the ten total years in the sample data. My current approach is aggregating the data using `length`, storing the `id`s that fulfil the requirement as a string and then using said string to subset the original data:

```
data[data$id %in% as.character(subset(aggregate(value ~ id, data = data, FUN = length), value >= 5)$id), ]
```

This would eliminate `D` since it only has `value` data for two years.

However, in a second step I would also like to eliminate `C` on the grounds that it does not offer data for five *consecutive* years but just for two periods of four years each. What would be the most beginner-friendly way of doing this? Please note that I do by no means insist on the previous steps if more elegant or sophisticated steps exist.

---

**Edit:**

Because of subsequent questions around the original data, this is the output of `dput(head(data))` (`DSCD` corresponds to `id`, `WC02999` to `value`, `year` is the same):

```
structure(list(DSCD = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("13082U", 
"13410M", "13489T", "13519D", "13542D", "135490", "13635T", "13643N", 
"13658P", "13702V", "13703E", "13703L", "13725W", "13760R", "13767F", 
"13767M", "13807C", "13906U", "13922L", "13925P", "13966W", "13968J", 
"13970M", "14048T", "142401", "142439", "142586", "142706", "142789", 
"142792", "142809", "142947", "142948", "143170", "143171", "143189", 
"143207", "143238", "143446", "143553", "143576", "14360D", "143635", 
"143641", "143710", "143711", "143723", "143728", "143787", "143796", 
"143984", "14530M", "14530U", "14858W", "14907P", "15144T", "15314M", 
"15349L", "15407X", "255083", "2566RQ", "26019X", "2622K8", "2622LM", 
"2623J2", "2628HQ", "263394", "263399", "263466", "263659", "263860", 
"264348", "264403", "264502", "264716", "264721", "264723", "265104", 
"265624", "269377", "269491", "269520", "269968", "269973", "27007F", 
"270084", "270520", "270522", "270550", "270903", "270950", "271001", 
"27183E", "27194R", "27225R", "273293", "273296", "273298", "273300", 
"27421F", "27421M", "27421N", "27421P", "27422H", "27422J", "27422W", 
"27423J", "27423M", "27423R", "27424C", "27424L", "275192", "275297", 
"275344", "275350", "275354", "275356", "275367", "275497", "275508", 
"275510", "275512", "275514", "275516", "275518", "275536", "275549", 
"275552", "275554", "275556", "275562", "275577", "275579", "275580", 
"275583", "275590", "275598", "275822", "275855", "275903", "27598M", 
"27605Q", "276355", "276363", "276452", "276461", "276464", "276466", 
"278147", "278180", "278248", "278333", "278413", "278415", "278417", 
"278421", "278603", "278609", "278610", "278650", "278652", "278655", 
"278657", "278659", "278712", "278713", "278946", "280592", "280598", 
"280751", "280754", "280766", "280833", "281876", "28198R", "282398", 
"283766", "283806", "283998", "284265", "284267", "284304", "285240", 
"285242", "285246", "28539J", "285575", "285577", "285579", "2865J8", 
"287251", "287254", "287257", "287259", "287265", "287489", "287931", 
"287936", "287938", "287941", "287943", "288501", "288553", "288558", 
"288724", "288744", "288746", "288748", "288750", "288752", "288754", 
"28982V", "289889", "28990K", "290205", "290255", "290256", "290259", 
"290298", "290300", "290657", "290659", "290663", "290665", "290797", 
"290814", "290816", "290818", "290906", "290943", "291264", "291599", 
"291601", "291742", "291746", "291748", "291750", "291752", "291774", 
"291776", "291778", "29237N", "29251M", "295053", "295057", "295059", 
"295196", "295210", "295360", "295362", "295364", "295675", "295677", 
"295679", "295681", "295683", "295685", "295686", "295707", "295708", 
"295908", "295909", "295912", "296109", "296153", "296154", "296156", 
"296303", "296305", "296307", "296410", "296414", "296420", "29649E", 
"296628", "296630", "296746", "296748", "296750", "296752", "29764Q", 
"298551", "298687", "299014", "29946N", "299479", "29955U", "29967U", 
"299685", "30061V", "300623", "300951", "301573", "301575", "30169F", 
"301774", "30244P", "30409V", "307001", "307005", "307010", "307014", 
"307055", "307076", "307077", "307093", "307230", "307263", "307288", 
"307290", "307291", "307314", "307315", "307420", "307524", "307550", 
"307636", "307668", "307694", "307705", "308398", "308918", "308930", 
"308994", "309065", "309111", "309354", "309642", "309735", "309869", 
"309873", "309899", "31131W", "31172T", "31178L", "31209N", "31245C", 
"31311H", "31333F", "31341D", "31446E", "31466D", "31689E", "31774V", 
"31915V", "31915W", "31948P", "32000F", "32085X", "32139T", "32141M", 
"32146D", "32187V", "32197D", "32309D", "32318H", "32320H", "32331J", 
"32364X", "32396J", "32396L", "32507N", "32508D", "32551W", "32564F", 
"32606U", "32633H", "32647K", "32674V", "32744F", "32766R", "32798R", 
"32799T", "32854P", "32949T", "35615H", "35623C", "35631J", "35649C", 
"35654N", "35654V", "35661J", "35700K", "35733D", "35785W", "35786F", 
"35904L", "35923C", "35934N", "35940Q", "35975T", "35983E", "35993H", 
"35993N", "36055V", "36061Q", "36069C", "36073V", "36079W", "36082V", 
"36108D", "36122Q", "36133K", "36133M", "36133P", "36133R", "36135V", 
"36136C", "36136K", "36155V", "36175X", "36192J", "36197Q", "36197U", 
"36204U", "36237T", "36237W", "36246R", "36246U", "36249U", "36266L", 
"36267H", "36286E", "36296K", "410969", "41186R", "411924", "411927", 
"41197P", "41201P", "41203K", "41203P", "41221D", "41221V", "412262", 
"412460", "412462", "412464", "41246U", "412647", "412710", "412712", 
"41271T", "41272K", "41279H", "41293V", "413018", "413299", "41330C", 
"413324", "41351H", "41357V", "41361N", "41382Q", "41385H", "41403N", 
"414110", "414116", "414118", "41431J", "414352", "41442V", "41442X", 
"414709", "41481M", "41481R", "41481U", "41497H", "415066", "41507F", 
"41507M", "41518W", "41528R", "41528V", "41639R", "50009X", "50010D", 
"50131F", "50147K", "50263K", "50277N", "50277R", "50291T", "50310R", 
"50315N", "50315Q", "50322L", "50343Q", "50367F", "50367M", "50367P", 
"50385U", "50420Q", "50420T", "50440R", "504440", "504458", "504531", 
"504634", "504654", "504656", "504663", "504667", "504712", "504866", 
"505048", "505049", "505050", "505070", "50507N", "50507P", "505087", 
"505090", "50514Q", "505241", "505346", "505368", "505385", "505459", 
"505463", "505480", "505509", "505572", "505639", "505656", "50575H", 
"50575J", "505843", "505973", "50625F", "50634D", "50634F", "50697L", 
"50697N", "50698Q", "50704T", "50760Q", "507664", "507726", "50781W", 
"50788W", "50820E", "50828F", "50888T", "50929D", "50935U", "51033J", 
"51066H", "51086W", "51163N", "51164L", "51168F", "51174K", "51196F", 
"51227R", "51234R", "51238Q", "51265X", "51298F", "51299R", "51299U", 
"51305C", "51346H", "51406N", "51452K", "51452U", "51579X", "51804X", 
"51927K", "51936U", "51968W", "531883", "53415D", "53534D", "53545E", 
"53588M", "53614P", "53651F", "53720E", "539623", "539841", "539873", 
"540193", "54057T", "54072N", "54124K", "54133X", "54143U", "54164D", 
"54175W", "54334L", "54450P", "54468X", "670386", "670387", "670390", 
"670394", "670409", "670535", "671152", "671232", "671262", "671264", 
"671294", "671469", "671475", "671550", "674731", "674733", "675230", 
"67612N", "676138", "676296", "676450", "676593", "67663T", "676648", 
"676756", "676768", "676770", "676774", "676804", "679114", "679205", 
"679384", "679386", "679411", "67941K", "679458", "679581", "679684", 
"679687", "679732", "679821", "68073E", "681070", "681179", "681309", 
"681441", "681668", "681674", "681771", "681772", "681773", "681874", 
"681876", "681945", "681983", "68270J", "68330Q", "684942", "684967", 
"684982", "68535U", "68572U", "686002", "686087", "686088", "686119", 
"686235", "686274", "686275", "686276", "68636X", "686654", "686792", 
"686871", "686872", "686874", "686946", "686947", "68703V", "687385", 
"68780X", "687848", "687958", "688024", "688025", "688026", "688137", 
"688158", "688190", "688282", "688312", "688553", "688622", "688646", 
"688700", "688731", "688733", "688751", "688856", "688877", "688955", 
"688957", "69000P", "69000T", "690040", "690041", "690166", "690168", 
"69026L", "69026N", "690326", "690415", "690792", "690825", "690976", 
"69150T", "69262V", "69297L", "69484Q", "69505M", "695098", "695099", 
"695101", "695102", "695251", "695328", "695379", "695383", "695478", 
"695480", "695482", "695484", "695485", "695615", "695670", "695671", 
"695672", "695790", "695792", "695793", "695794", "695996", "69695F", 
"697063", "697098", "697105", "697126", "697269", "697334", "697457", 
"697458", "697459", "69746D", "697528", "697530", "697532", "697534", 
"697712", "697714", "697835", "697970", "697976", "697979", "697998", 
"698000", "698008", "698016", "698018", "698163", "698267", "698269", 
"698271", "698273", "698445", "698447", "698449", "698473", "698501", 
"698675", "698738", "698775", "698796", "698798", "698822", "698853", 
"698855", "698857", "698872", "69892Q", "698940", "698943", "698975", 
"698992", "698994", "698996", "698998", "69900U", "69913H", "7001NE", 
"700409", "7019JR", "702300", "702699", "702812", "71973L", "72464R", 
"72464U", "72483F", "72568X", "729108", "729175", "729244", "729304", 
"72931E", "729376", "729407", "729532", "729536", "72958C", "729717", 
"72981J", "729951", "729956", "729998", "74032R", "74042L", "74053J", 
"741302", "741413", "741639", "741676", "741846", "741915", "741916", 
"745070", "7450TR", "74513K", "74653D", "7465F5", "749786", "755072", 
"755075", "755076", "755380", "755415", "755530", "755589", "755661", 
"755671", "755724", "756342", "756395", "756463", "756507", "756550", 
"756551", "756648", "75678H", "756801", "756841", "75688C", "75688E", 
"77123D", "77265W", "772756", "772785", "772836", "77287U", "77287W", 
"77338T", "7734G7", "77414X", "775004", "775005", "775006", "775008", 
"775010", "775011", "775012", "775013", "775014", "775017", "775018", 
"775019", "775027", "775028", "775030", "775031", "775032", "775033", 
"775034", "775038", "775039", "775042", "775045", "775047", "775048", 
"775049", "775050", "775054", "775055", "775056", "775058", "775059", 
"775060", "775061", "775063", "775065", "775066", "775067", "775073", 
"775075", "775076", "775077", "775079", "775080", "775081", "775082", 
"775083", "775084", "775087", "775088", "775090", "775091", "775092", 
"775093", "775096", "775097", "775099", "775100", "775101", "775103", 
"775104", "775108", "775109", "775110", "775112", "775114", "775118", 
"775119", "775121", "775123", "775125", "775126", "775127", "775129", 
"775130", "775134", "775135", "775136", "775137", "775140", "775143", 
"775144", "775145", "775148", "775149", "775150", "775151", "775152", 
"775153", "775155", "775156", "775157", "775158", "775159", "775160", 
"775161", "775164", "775165", "775166", "775169", "775170", "775171", 
"775172", "775174", "775176", "775178", "775182", "775183", "775184", 
"775185", "775188", "775189", "775195", "775198", "775200", "775201", 
"775205", "775206", "775207", "775208", "775212", "775213", "775215", 
"775216", "77541C", "775543", "775607", "775647", "775650", "775665", 
"775668", "775671", "775672", "775692", "775697", "775700", "775725", 
"775744", "775766", "775787", "775824", "775828", "775850", "775863", 
"775866", "775869", "775875", "779095", "779096", "779393", "865236", 
"86529X", "8653LJ", "8655QU", "866013", "866015", "86605R", "866071", 
"8660QZ", "866132", "86624J", "8663YK", "866649", "866802", "866806", 
"866807", "866814", "866815", "866816", "866822", "866827", "866833", 
"866835", "866858", "866859", "866860", "866863", "866864", "866865", 
"866867", "866869", "866870", "866871", "866872", "866873", "866875", 
"866877", "866879", "866881", "866884", "866885", "866887", "866890", 
"866891", "866892", "866893", "866894", "866895", "866897", "866900", 
"866901", "866902", "866903", "866904", "866905", "866906", "866907", 
"866909", "866910", "866911", "866913", "866916", "866917", "866918", 
"866919", "866920", "866921", "866922", "866923", "866924", "866925", 
"866926", "866928", "866930", "866931", "866932", "866933", "866934", 
"866935", "866936", "866937", "866940", "866942", "866943", "866946", 
"866947", "866950", "866951", "866953", "866954", "866955", "866956", 
"866957", "866960", "866961", "866962", "866964", "866965", "866966", 
"866968", "866969", "866970", "866971", "866972", "866973", "866974", 
"866975", "866978", "866979", "86780E", "8696U9", "8700H2", "8701KK", 
"8706KL", "87136T", "87151K", "87234V", "87279Q", "87310U", "87314V", 
"8735UU", "8736A3", "8752P5", "875876", "876246", "876251", "87677L", 
"87755D", "87772J", "87779F", "87809P", "8784CJ", "88045W", "881098", 
"88188Q", "882059", "882067", "882075", "882246", "882268", "882284", 
"882292", "882294", "882302", "882362", "882363", "882778", "8871WY", 
"888493", "888823", "888905", "888906", "8894H4", "8896F7", "8898MM", 
"8908A4", "8910Z1", "892381", "892568", "89275V", "89367H", "89368N", 
"896322", "896382", "896424", "896456", "896530", "896567", "896601", 
"896673", "896674", "896729", "897384", "897801", "898618", "898696", 
"898719", "898772", "898780", "899004", "899005", "899070", "899187", 
"902191", "902192", "902193", "9030YZ", "904881", "905009", "905071", 
"905243", "9055XU", "9058DE", "9063LK", "91099V", "91106A", "9110CP", 
"9110DH", "9111KD", "91131Q", "9113KN", "9113M4", "9113M7", "9120DC", 
"912318", "912337", "91240F", "912433", "912624", "912819", "912977", 
"916039", "916118", "916181", "916235", "916341", "9163ND", "9163ZM", 
"9166LC", "916710", "916776", "916825", "916970", "9170JT", "9171C2", 
"92103H", "9211R1", "9211R3", "921260", "921285", "921289", "92206E", 
"922399", "922819", "922888", "923117", "92318K", "923256", "923533", 
"923536", "923537", "923551", "923744", "923754", "9237G2", "923922", 
"92670W", "9268RU", "9270F3", "9270K3", "9271H6", "9274QU", "92760Y", 
"9278R4", "9288NU", "929015", "929016", "929017", "929018", "929019", 
"929020", "929021", "929022", "929024", "929025", "929028", "929029", 
"929030", "929031", "929032", "929033", "929035", "929040", "929041", 
"929042", "929044", "929046", "929047", "929048", "929049", "929050", 
"929051", "929052", "929053", "929054", "929055", "929057", "929058", 
"929059", "929060", "929062", "929063", "929066", "929067", "929070", 
"929073", "929075", "929077", "929078", "929080", "929083", "929097", 
"929098", "929099", "929100", "929101", "929106", "929114", "929116", 
"929117", "929118", "929119", "929121", "929123", "929124", "929125", 
"929126", "929128", "929129", "929130", "929131", "929133", "9292L9", 
"929541", "929542", "929560", "929918", "930095", "9301KQ", "930216", 
"930376", "930606", "9307AJ", "9308NW", "93125T", "9314FE", "933063", 
"933366", "933371", "933373", "9344KT", "9344ZA", "936292", "936326", 
"936473", "936474", "936476", "936477", "936479", "936480", "936481", 
"936482", "936499", "9364D1", "936539", "936540", "936870", "936871", 
"936905", "936906", "936907", "936908", "936909", "936910", "936912", 
"936913", "936914", "936915", "936931", "936934", "936935", "936936", 
"936938", "936939", "936940", "93730Z", "9373ZG", "9374XF", "937927", 
"938744", "944429", "944766", "944835", "944954", "945210", "945456", 
"945528", "945728", "945780", "945793", "946049", "946050", "946250", 
"946281", "9463X2", "946403", "9468LA", "9470PN", "950831", "950958", 
"950989", "951184", "951186", "951188", "951189", "951190", "951192", 
"951194", "951195", "951196", "951197", "951198", "951199", "951201", 
"951203", "951204", "951206", "951207", "951209", "951211", "951212", 
"951213", "951214", "951216", "951217", "951219", "951220", "951221", 
"951222", "951224", "951225", "951226", "951227", "951228", "951229", 
"951230", "951231", "951232", "951233", "951234", "951235", "951347", 
"951476", "951477", "951478", "951487", "951491", "951493", "951496", 
"951632", "951636", "951639", "951640", "951642", "951643", "951651", 
"951657", "951659", "951660", "951661", "951663", "951678", "951679", 
"951680", "951683", "951686", "951691", "951737", "951738", "951741", 
"951747", "951750", "951752", "951755", "951759", "951772", "951774", 
"951776", "951778", "952089", "952255", "952263", "952264", "952266", 
"952267", "952272", "952277", "952279", "952280", "952281", "952283", 
"952284", "952285", "952299", "9532DJ", "9557N4", "97498V", "981853", 
"9826H9", "982910", "992562", "9928GV", "997704", "998222", "999503", 
"999564", "999661"), class = "factor"), WC06001 = c("7C SOLARPARKEN AG", 
"7C SOLARPARKEN AG", "7C SOLARPARKEN AG", "7C SOLARPARKEN AG", 
"7C SOLARPARKEN AG", "7C SOLARPARKEN AG"), WC07021 = c(4911, 
4911, 4911, 4911, 4911, 4911), WC07015 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), WC02001 = c(18, 4225, 14290, 4736, 
2607, 32255), WC02003 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), WC02008 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WC02149 = c(9, 540, 298, 449, 
819, 3655), WC02250 = c(NA, 207, 2, 2, 0, 15787), WC02201 = c(27, 
24391, 35837, 30144, 55952, 72650), WC02501 = c(0, 282, 706, 
583, 594, 159753), WC02301 = c(NA, 364, 893, 885, 1014, 169410
), WC02401 = c(NA, 82, 187, 302, 420, 9657), WC02652 = c(0, 19949, 
18999, 25200, 21977, 72322), WC02999 = c(27, 44829, 55544, 55929, 
78523, 320512), WC02654 = c(0, 19952, 18909, 19200, 15663, 73062
), WC02655 = c(0, 3, 17, 78, 190, 740), WC02300 = c(40, 44829, 
56874, 57705, 78523, 323110), WC03051 = c(NA, 846, 4297, 3298, 
10444, 18664), WC03101 = c(40, 8763, 14817, 11353, 39297, 57920
), WC03251 = c(0, 0, 9378, 9436, 0, 143607), WC03260 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WC03273 = c(0, 
472, 256, 30, 0, 394), WC03351 = c(40, 9235, 23152, 19505, 39297, 
202172), WC03401 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), WC03426 = c(NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 657), WC03451 = c(NA, 
NA, 0, 0, 0, 0), WC03501 = c(-13, 35594, 32392, 36424, 39226, 
117683), WC03999 = c(27, 44829, 55544, 55929, 78523, 320512), 
    WC01001 = c(0, 52582, 62208, 85370, 142755, 117178), WC01151 = c(47, 
    71, 207, 243, 286, 6097), WC01100 = c(-47, 6145, 3559, 7987, 
    21592, 21652), WC01250 = c(-116, 4322, -5951, -172, 11342, 
    15576), WC01266 = c(NA, 42, 155, 224, 494, 325), WC01262 = c(54, 
    18, 199, 381, -2358, 231), WC01251 = c(0, 106, 849, 532, 
    922, 10075), WC01401 = c(-62, 4146, -7150, -99, 8554, 8073
    ), WC01451 = c(NA, 1523, -2717, 177, 3586, 2336), WC01501 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, -12), WC01201 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WC18140 = c(NA, 214, 516, 
    576, 757, NA), WC18276 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WC18275 = c(0, 130, 24, 0, 
    2, 41), WC18191 = c(-62, 4252, -6301, 433, 9476, 18148), 
    WC18198 = c(-15, 4323, -6094, 676, 9762, 24245), WC18155 = c(-69, 
    4393, -5744, 71, 11628, 21673), WC01268 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WC01352 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WC18324 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WC04001 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WC04051 = c(NA, 
    69, 193, 182, 174, 5604), WC04151 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WC04201 = c(-35, 
    3693, -4304, -170, 7285, -2583), WC04831 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WC04860 = c(-25, 
    -8775, -3315, -12496, -1508, 28836), WC04890 = c(0, 13258, 
    14055, 3309, 3298, -3249), WC04797 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WC04870 = c(-3, 
    544, 675, 367, 339, 3380), WC04401 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WC04821 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WC04149 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WC04501 = c(NA, 
    12582, -14369, 9384, 5833, -24790), WC04601 = c(NA, 203, 
    675, 111, 343, 8220), WC04701 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WC04551 = c(NA, NA, NA, 0, 
    0, 0), WC04148 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), WC04150 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WC04851 = c(-22, 3939, 10065, 
    -9554, 1451, 22207), WC04500 = c(49, 32984, 10609, 4366, 
    -13873, 216410), WC04900 = c(NA, 15641, 5392, -2229, -2136, 
    -1925), WC04057 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), WC04811 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), CURRENCY = c("E", "E", "E", 
    "E", "E", "E"), year = c(2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009
    ), active = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c("2004.1535", 
"2005.1535", "2006.1535", "2007.1535", "2008.1535", "2009.1535"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your dput output is incomplete.  Make sure to copy everything and paste.

Comment: Yes, I missed the last line. That's the complete output now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` version.  I'm filtering out missing `value` to get a clean count by id after `group_by` (must be at least 5).  Using `rle` and`diff` to obtain run lengths and values (counts of runs), which must be length of at least 5 and exist at least once.

```
 data %>%
      filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
      group_by(id) %>%
      filter(
        n() >= 5 &
          any(rle(diff(year))$lengths >= 4 & rle(diff(year))$values >= 1)
      )
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I tried running the adapted code but got `Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`. Any idea what this points to? `id` is a character string but both `year` and `value` are numerics so I'm a bit lost with the error message.

Comment: That's strange, I'm seeing `data$id` as a factor.  can you run `str(data)` after creating `data` in a clean environment?  The only dependency should be `dplyr`, you can also try updating that package with `install.packages("dplyr")`.

Comment: I was wrong about the type in the original dataset and changed it accordingly through `as.factor`. Running the code now results in `Warning message:
Factor 'fct_explicit_na(id, na_level = "(Missing)")' contains implicit NA, consider using 'forcats::fct_explicit_na'` although there are no `NA`s anywhere in the `id` column. The problem thus seems to be in my data although I do not know where.

Comment: I would make sure DSCD is a factor, WC02999 is numeric and year is an integer in your dataset.  Also strip down your data to those variables to isolate the issue.  I suspect the additional columns in your data are making your test data not reproduce the issue.

Comment: Your suspicion was correct. Once I subset the data and changed the types your script worked exactly as it should have done in the beginning. That of course left me with the task of somehow aligning the results with my original data. I chose to use row names (created through `tibble`'s `rownames_to_column`) for this by adding a second `dplyr` operation: `original_data %>% filter(row_name %in% sample_data$row_name)`. This finally returned the results I was hoping for. It's probably a cumbersome workaround for experienced users but does the trick for now. Thanks for your perseverence!

Comment: Glad you got it working.  It would be helpful in the future to have the reproducible example (test data) match the "real" data in these respects (data type, number of columns).  This way any solutions can account for these extra variables.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `tapply()` function from base `R`. For each `data$id` inside the `tapply()` function, `!is.na(data$value)` produces a logical vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE` and run it through `function(x)`.  Inside this function, `rle(x)` counts the number of each value (`T`, `F`) occurs without an interruptions.  e.g T,T,T,F,F,T,T will produce 3,2,2, meaning T occurs 3 times in a row, then F twice followed by T twice. Of these counts, we are only interested in the counts of `TRUE` that represents non-`NA` values in your data, which is ensured by the `rle(x)$values==T` part of the function.  Finally, a vector `max.rle` containing the counts of lengths of `TRUE` is generated and run through `ifelse()` which evaluates if the length of `max.rle` is > 0 then return the `max()` of the vector otherwise return zero.  This condition is necessary because if you have an entry with all NA, then it will produce `-Inf`, and this `ifelse` command handles that.

```
# order dataframe on id and year
data <- data[order(data$id, data$year), ]
# get the max length of non-NA stretche in values column
max.rle <- tapply(!is.na(data$value), data$id, function(x) {
  max.vec <- rle(x)$length[rle(x)$values==T]
  ifelse(length(max.vec) > 0, max(max.vec), 0)
})
# remove those ids that has stretch length less than 5
data <- data[data$id %in% names(max.rle[max.rle >= 5]), ]
# print data
data

   id year     value
1   A 2008 116.57251
2   A 2009  92.22958
3   A 2010  68.67486
4   A 2011  86.67054
5   A 2012  85.74104
6   A 2013  83.21088
7   A 2014  97.20029
8   A 2015 127.53420
9   A 2016  86.97861
10  A 2017 119.10791
11  B 2008 105.26708
12  B 2009  72.47399
13  B 2010  85.00305
14  B 2011  93.80867
15  B 2012 113.37334
16  B 2013 116.63578
17  B 2014 119.41421
18  B 2015 108.64411
19  B 2016  73.80403
20  B 2017 143.75300
```

Comment: Thanks for example. Could you kindly explain what the `function (x)` in `tapply` does? I tried to adapt the code but received countless warnings (e.g. `In max(rle(x)$length[rle(x)$value == T]) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf`). The resulting `max.rle` vector is thus full of `Inf`s and not of much help for the next step.

Comment: I added the full description and modified the tapply to handle the error/warnings you were getting. Your warning happens probably because you have an ID which had all the NA. But the fixed function should handle it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. However, I checked all my `id`s (`sum(is.na(DEU_active$DSCD))` returned `[1] 0`) and there doesn't seem to be a problem with any of them. Running the adapted code now results in a `max.rle` vector full of `0`s although I clearly see manually that many `id`s fulfil the criterion of >= 5 `year`s. Is there any clear indication what could be wrong with the actual data if it's not because of the code?

Comment: Can you try if it work on the data here in your original question? In  `(sum(is.na(DEU_active$DSCD))` is DSCD the id or value column?  Can you share the dput(head(data)) of your real data?

Comment: Apologies for the copy-paste error. `DSCD` is equal to `id`. See the original post for an overview of the real data.

Comment: The code should work as long as you specify the arguments inside the `tapply` correctly.  Pay attention to the order of `!is.na(data$value), data$id,` insidet he `tapply`.  I tested the code on the data provided in the question and it works on my machine.  I am not sure why it is not working for you.  This is a silly question, but did you replace the `id` with `DSCD` and `value` with whatever the name is in your data for that column?

Comment: I hopefully did. As you now know the dataset, the adapted code that I copied and ran was `max.rle <- tapply(!is.na(DEU_active$WC02999), DEU_active$DSCD, function(x) {
    max.vec <- rle(x)$length[rle(x)$WC02999==T]
    ifelse(length(max.vec) > 0, max(max.vec), 0)
})`.

Comment: Okay, looking at your data, one final thing I can suggest is to use `data=droplevels(data)` once you have the final data ready to be run through this code.  Add this line right before `data <- data[order(data$id, data$year), ]`.  Let me know if it works, otherwise sorry mate. Good luck.

Comment: Sadly it didn't. Thanks for your patience though.

Answer (score 0):

The second condition seems to take care of the first one too. Calculate difference between years for each groups and see if there are at least four `1`

```
d = data[!is.na(data$value),]

d[ave(d$year, d$id, FUN = function(x){
    delta = diff(sort(x))
    if ( with(rle(delta), max(lengths[values == 1])) >=4 ){
        rep(TRUE, length(x))
    }else {
        rep(FALSE, length(x))
    }
}) == 1,]
#   id year     value
#1   A 2008 127.41917
#2   A 2009  88.70604
#3   A 2010 107.26257
#4   A 2011 112.65725
#5   A 2012 108.08537
#6   A 2013  97.87751
#7   A 2014 130.23044
#8   A 2015  98.10682
#9   A 2016 140.36847
#10  A 2017  98.74572
#11  B 2008 126.09739
#12  B 2009 145.73291
#13  B 2010  72.22279
#14  B 2011  94.42422
#15  B 2012  97.33357
#16  B 2013 112.71901
#17  B 2014  94.31494
#18  B 2015  46.87089
#19  B 2016  51.19066
#20  B 2017 126.40227
```

---

```
#DATA
    set.seed(42)
    data <- data.frame(id = c(rep("A", 10),
                              rep("B", 10),
                              rep("C", 10),
                              rep("D", 10)),
                       year = rep(2008:2017, 4),
                       value = c(rnorm(10, mean = 100, sd = 20),
                                 rnorm(10, mean = 100, sd = 20),
                                 rnorm(4, mean = 100, sd = 20),
                                 rep(NA, 2),
                                 rnorm(4, mean = 100, sd = 20),
                                 rnorm(2, mean = 100, sd = 20),
                                 rep(NA, 8)))
```